# setValuesForKeys is not working in swift 4 in Xcode 9

Tags: swift

I have a `[String : NSObject]` var named `dict`. When it put it like this:

```
let test = AnchorGroup(dict)
```

and then I use `print(test.tag_name)` I get nothing on command line.

I try to print the dict in `init(dict : dict)`. It has the correct info.

Here is my dict content:
["tag_id": 1, "tag_name": LOL, "push_nearby": 0, "push_vertical_screen": 0]

```
class AnchorGroup: NSObject {
    //房间列表，是一个数组 room list an Array
    var room_list : [[String : NSObject]]?
    //频道名 channel name
    var tag_name : String = ""
    //频道图标 channel icon name
    var icon_name : String = "home_header_normal"

    init(dict : [String : NSObject]) {
        super.init()
        //can corretly output the dict content to command line.
        print(dict["tag_name"]!)
        //not work,when I create a instance in somewhere,it get nothing.
        setValuesForKeys(dict)
    }

    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forUndefinedKey key: String) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the exact output (as text) of `print(dict)`.

Comment: let test : [String : NSObject] = ["tag_name" : "mytest" as NSString]
                let group = AnchorGroup(dict: test)
       
                print(group.tag_name)       I didn't get any output content on command line.    please remove the print(dict["tag_name"]!) in class AnchorGroup and try it.

Comment: my Xcode version is 9.4.1.  I will have a try on playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `print("bad key: \(key)")` to the `setValue(_ value: Any?, forUndefinedKey key: String)` function you will see that `tag_name` is an undefined key.

The problem is that all of this key-value coding functionality of `NSObject` requires compatibility with Objective-C. So any property in your class that you want to work with key-value coding like this must be marked with `@objc`.

Change:

```
var tag_name : String = ""
```

to:

```
@objc var tag_name : String = ""
```

And the code:

```
let test : [String : NSObject] = ["tag_name" : "mytest" as NSString]
let group = AnchorGroup(dict: test)
print(group.tag_name)
```

gives the expected results.

Update your other properties as needed.

Comment: what does @objc mean?  why do I add this?  only key-value need it?